# @vue.cli 4.2.3 Add Expires headers

Tags: vue.js, caching, vue-router

How to do this at all? I am very new to caching and have no idea how caching is done. But GTMetics YSlow recommends me to Add Expires headers, and I have no idea how to start fixing it on vue cli.

Comment: Where are you serving the vue app from? Is it a CDN or an express backend for instance?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. How can i check?
All i know is I have created an app in vue.cli and I run it with command npm run serve.

Answer (score 0):

addding an expires header is not done in your code but in your .htaccess if you're using apache server for example.
Gtmatrix also provided an article on how you can do this.
https://gtmetrix.com/serve-static-assets-with-an-efficient-cache-policy.html
So you don't need to worry in your code as there is not a plugin to do this in Vuejs or any framework